# Why the abstract method is not executing in the following code?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, abstract-methods

I am pasting the below code :

```
 abstract public class test
    {
        abstract public void add(int a, int b);

    }

    class Program : test
    {
        public void add(decimal a, decimal b)
        {
            decimal c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Decimal Addition : {0}", c);
        }

        public override void add(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Addition : {0} ", c);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.add(10, 111);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I am not able to understand why the above Abstract class is not executing ?
the above code runs perfect which produces output also.
My question is even after overriding the abstract method in the Program class still when calling add() method why the non abstract method is executing and abstract method is not ?

Also If I change the program to :

```
 abstract public class test
{
    abstract public void add(int a, int b);

}

class Program : test
{
    public void add(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        decimal c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Decimal Addition : {0}", c);
    }

    public override void add(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Addition : {0} ", c);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        test obj = new Program();
        obj.add(10, 111);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Then my Abstract method is executing and giving me desired result. Please explain anyone. what is actually happening in the line below. I know it very basic question but i am bit confused over here. please help ! Thanks in advance.

```
test obj = new Program();
```

Comment: What exactly is happening differently than you expect?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: as above have said, also, you aren't really using your abstract class.  Perhaps you want to do `test obj = new Program();`  which will create a new program but hold it as a "test"

Comment: Abstract methods do not execute. They don't have any implementation. It's still very unclear what your question is.

Comment: I am sorry but I have tried my best to explain the scenario where I got confused. It may be a very basic concept in OOPS but now I am quite confused with program behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because any method declared in derive class has more priority than base  inherited methods.

If you want to call `add(int a, int b)` you will need to tell the compiler that `add(decimal a, decimal b)` does not exist. This is by casting it to `test`

```
abstract public class test
{
    abstract public void add(int a, int b);

}

class Program : test
{
    public void add(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        decimal c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Decimal Addition : {0}", c);
    }

    public override void add(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Addition : {0} ", c);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test obj = new Program();
        obj.add(10, 111);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to cast it, you can declare `add(decimal a, decimal b);` into the abstract class.
Like so:

```
abstract public class test
{
    abstract public void add(int a, int b);

    abstract public void add(decimal a, decimal b);
}

public class Program : test
{

    public override void add(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Addition : {0} ", c);
    }
    public override void add(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        decimal c = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Decimal Addition : {0}", c);
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.add(10, 111);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @Bob, but then when I executed your second code why i am only getting Addition and not both i.e., "Addition" and "Decimal Addition" in the console output ?

Comment: @Tony why do you expect both overloads to be called?

Comment: You can never execute two method with 1 call. To do that you will need to call twice. The 2nd one being `obj.add(10m, 111m);`, where `m` will tell compiler this is a decimal

Comment: @Bob Thanks a lot. Yes Thank you!

Comment: A detailed explanation of the reason why derive class methods are chosen over inherited methods can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117105/net-inheritance-and-method-overloading.